# Writing a value to an existing file repeatedly

Tags: python, c

I have a file that looks something like this:

```
76.049515 38.887974
20.341053 16.956047
72.749557 20.119661
28.935022 4.174813
...       ...
```

I want to add a column to the file with the same value (1 or 0) so that the file looks like this:

```
76.049515 38.887974 1
20.341053 16.956047 1
72.749557 20.119661 1 
28.935022 4.174813 1
```

I'm not sure how to go about it; anything in C or Python would work.

Comment: can you create a new file and then replace the old one? then it would be easy.

Comment: Sure. That would also be fine.

Comment: @user3288886 so you know how to do that already?

Comment: I'm trying to do that right now. So far, nope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script will do what you are looking for.

```
infile = open("inpu.txt", 'r') # open file for reading
outfile = open("output.txt","a") # open file for appending

line = infile.readline()    # Invokes readline() method on file
while line:
  outfile.write(line.strip("\n")+" 1\n")
  line = infile.readline()

infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

A nice detailed explanation of it is at this [location](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2009-February/066974.html) (along with other potential solutions)

Summary:

> the newline is at the end of the line, and thus the -d is coming at
>   the beginning. To work that out, we use string.strip() which allows us
>   to remove certain characters from the beginning and end of a string:

The script above produces this:

```
76.049515 38.887974 1
20.341053 16.956047 1
72.749557 20.119661 1
28.935022 4.174813 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much! For the answer and the link. That helps a lot.

Comment: @user3288886 If this answer do solved your problem, you should accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You [`open`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) with [`with clause`](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/183753-with-clause/), read the lines to a list, add `" 1"` at the end of each element in the list, and write back at last:

```
with open('a.x', 'r+') as f:
    newlines=[line.strip()+' 1\n' for line in f] #strip off '\n's and then add ' 1\n'
    f.seek(0) #move to the start of file to overwrite it.
    f.writelines(newlines) #write the lines back.
#file closed automatically out of the with clause scope
```